# Can't seem to understand the Sencha products

Tags: extjs

I'm preparing to develop some mobile apps for Android, iOS and WP7. Having heard a lot about Sencha, I was having a look at their products but can't figure out which of their products would help me (at the very least) in creating the interface for the app.

Sencha touch it seems is only for web applications (that can be deployed through a web browser).

What about Sencha Ext Designer. Is that also for web apps, or does that help build the UI for native apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building a mobile app, you'd use Sencha Touch (prior to version 2, you'd couple that with something like [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) to deploy it). It will 'look' like a native application but really it is still a webpage minus the chrome; no Sencha product builds native applications.

Ext Designer helps create interfaces for [Ext JS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/), their JavaScript framework to build desktop-like widgets so not related to Sencha Touch.

I hope that helps :)